# Partition large json files with ADF dataflow

Tags: json, dataflow, azure-data-factory

We are getting large json files from an API and we would like to load these files in CosmosDB/MongoDB. There is a size limit for files in CosmosDB/MongoDB.

We are trying to partition the file using ADF dataflow. If we put a certain number of partition, we are always getting 2 files and one of them with 0 byte. We are trying to partition by Key - but ADF is not recognizing the Key and throwing "sink requires partition column error"

We would appreciate any help/guidance with this.

If you want to play with it, below is link for a dummy file
https://easyupload.io/hxg67n

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to use **Round robin partition technique**.

[image]

Round robin distributes data equally across partitions. Use round-robin when you don't have good key candidates to implement a solid, smart partitioning strategy. You can set the number of physical partitions.

> Note
>
> You need to evaluate the data size or the partition number of input
> data, then set reasonable partition number under "Optimize". For
> example, the cluster that you use in the data flow pipeline execution
> is 8 cores and the memory of each core is 20GB, but the input data is
> 1000GB with 10 partitions. If you directly run the data flow, it will
> meet the OOM issue because 1000GB/10 > 20GB, so it is better to set
> repartition number to 100 (1000GB/100 < 20GB).

Refer - Supported Sink types –
[Sink transformation in mapping data flow - Azure Data Factory & Azure Synapse | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-sink#supported-sinks)